# javascriptにrubyの変数を渡す

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

javascriptにrubyの変数の内容を渡したいと考えています。
具体的にはBootstrapのポップオーバーの内容をデータベースから持ってきたいです。

経験が浅いので、_common.js.erbを用意してrenderを呼び出すときに
渡す方法しか思いつきませんでした。
まだ試してはいないのですが、うまく動作すると思います。

２点教えていただきたいのですが、この方法でうまくいくでしょうか
また、この方法を採用した場合に機能毎にファイルを分けてしまうと
ソース自体が汚くなる気がします。他に賢い方法はないでしょうか？

_common.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // ポップオーバー
  $("#popover").popover({
      html: true,
      placement: "bottom",
      content: <%= ここに変数を渡したい！ %>
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

目的に合致しているかどうかはわかりませんが、こんなサンプルを作ってみました。
Nameをクリックすると誕生日がpopoverされます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

実装としてはJSのpopoverメソッドに引数を渡すよりも、タグのdata属性経由で渡す方がシンプルだと思います。

```
<% @people.each do |person| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= content_tag :span, 
            person.name, 
            data: { 
              toggle: :popover, 
              content: l(person.date_of_birth), 
              placement: :bottom 
            } 
      %>
    </td>
    <td><%= person.date_of_birth %></td>
    (省略)
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

HTMLはこんな感じで出力されます。

```
<span data-toggle="popover" data-content="1964-11-23" data-placement="bottom">
  Taro
</span>
```

そして、JS側はpopoverメソッドだけを単純にコールします。

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

今回のサンプルアプリケーションはGitHubに置いているので参考にしてみてください。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/js-popover-sandbox

もし、何らかの事情でタグのdata属性が使えないようであれば質問に理由を追記してください。

#### 追記

partial view(HTML)をpopoverで表示したいケースも書いておきます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
# views/people/_popover.html.erb
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
<%= l person.date_of_birth %>
```

```
# views/people/index.html.erb
<%= content_tag :span, 
      person.name, 
      data: { 
        toggle: :popover, 
        content: "#{render('popover', person: person)}", 
        placement: :bottom, 
        html: true 
      } 
%>
```

```
# output.html
<span data-toggle="popover" data-content="&lt;span class=&quot;glyphicon glyphicon-calendar&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
1964-11-23" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true">Taro</span>
```

コードは with-partial ブランチにあります。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/js-popover-sandbox/tree/with-partial

ちなみにHTMLバージョンを作った理由は質問のサンプルコードがこちらのページに載っているコードと似ていたからです。

http://chisuke.net/2013/09/13/bootstrap-3-0-0_popover/

Comment: お返事が遅くなり申し訳ありません。
rubyのコードでどうにかなる方でしたのでこちらを参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 3):

gonというgemを利用するとJavascriptにrubyの変数の値を渡すことができます。
[コチラ](http://qiita.com/yk-212/items/8d648b83e24a43af17ba)に簡単な使い方がまとまっています。